# Django ORM: get objects distinct on a column and ordered by another column

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have a Django model which (extremely simplified) looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    number = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

I'd like to get a list of unique `number`s, by reverse chronological order in which they appear.

So for example with this data (`date`s are ordered here for better legibility):

```
date         | number
-------------+-------
24/12/2014   | 12
23/12/2014   | 8
22/12/2014   | 8
21/12/2014   | 5
20/12/2014   | 12
19/12/2014   | 5
18/12/2014   | 14
```

I'd get a list that looks like this:

```
[12, 8, 5, 14]
```

Intuitively I'd write the query like this:

```
MyModel.objects.order_by('-date').distinct('number')
```

But this is invalid ORM code.

How do I solve this problem?

Note that the table in question contains several millions of rows with potentially a lot of repeated `number`s, so I can't solve this problem in a "naive" way (e.g. iterating over rows from `MyModel.objects.order_by('-date')` and picking up `number`s on the fly if they haven't been seen before).

Comment: Try this set(MyModel.objects.order_by('-date').values('number'))

Comment: @Sławek This would not work; in Python, a `set` is unordered. Thus there is no guarantee that the `number` values would be in the right order. Additionally, this would cause the entire queryset to be evaluated, which would be problematic if you had millions and millions of rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@mipadi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23896258/django-orm-get-objects-distinct-on-a-column-and-ordered-by-another-column/23897036#23897036) works great, but I'd prefer avoiding raw SQL in my codebase.

However his answer made it much easier to figure out a native ORM version, so thanks to him!
Here's the ORM version I came up with:

```
 results = MyModel.objects.values('number').annotate(m=Max('date')).order_by('-m')
 results = [r.number for r in results]
```

It seems like one should be able to do:

```
results = MyModel.objects.values('number').annotate(m=Max('date')).order_by('-m').values_list('number', flat=True)
```

But with Django 1.6, I get a `FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'm' into field.` error when adding the last `values_list` method. There might be a way around this, but I'm not bothered by the 2 line version enough to spend time figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a SQL `GROUP BY` statement, but truth be told, I can never remember how to do `GROUP BY` in Django's ORM, so I resort to raw SQL:

```
number_qs = MyModel.objects.raw("""
    SELECT
        id, MAX(date) AS date, number
    FROM
        myapp_mymodel
    GROUP BY
        number
    ORDER BY
        MAX(date) DESC;
""")
numbers = [n.number for n in number_qs]
```